# Scale Animation for SurfaceView

Tags: android, animation, scale, surfaceview

I'm trying to create a SurfaceView that scales down with animation(including it's black background canvas).
i've search for multiple ways but it looks as if the view isn't scaled correctly or doesn't scale at all.

this is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
         <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/gfxComponentContainer"
             android:layout_width="292dp"
             android:layout_height="260dp"
             android:background="@color/black" 
             android:gravity="center_horizontal">

             <SurfaceView
                  android:id="@+id/gfxComponent"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              />
          </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With no code or explanation  this is not going to get  helpful answer.  Post your animation xml and your surfaceview handling code.

Comment: @Elimicky, did you find an answer for this?  I've also been trying to use a scale animation on a SurfaceView object (in my case, Google Maps/Street View) with no luck either.

Comment: A SurfaceView has two parts, the Surface and the View. The Surface is an independent layer that sits behind the View UI layer. The View part behaves like any other view, but is normally transparent, so you can see through it to the Surface behind. Animating the Surface using View operations is problematic at best. TextureView, introduced in API 14, is usually more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceHolder.setSizeFromLayout() might be what you are (were) looking for. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setSizeFromLayout()